# django debug false and internal server error

Tags: django, heroku

im writing a project using django.

while it was in a development stage i used `DEBUG=TRUE`, but now i want to upload it to heroku for production.

i set `DEBUG=FALSE` and kept getting an internal server error, so i further investigated and found that i need to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']`, so i did..

i ran it with the localhost but i still kept getting internal server error.

what am i doing wrong? cause i can't figure it out?

also, what should i put in allowed host for heroku site?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Remember that static files directory when `debug = true` is no the same when debug is false

heroku uses whitenoise for static files.

Answer (score 0):

You need the domain you're accessing your server from in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Example:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com', ]
```

Yet, improperly configured `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should not result in internal server error responses (HTTP code 500) but in bad request responses (HTTP code 400).
Have you configured a way to log exceptions on your production server in order to investigate this?

Comment: i haven't configured a way to log exception on production, but before i even go there, i want to run it on my local host but it doesn't work. when i changed the allowed hosts from "localhost" to http://localhost:8000/ it gave me a 400 error code..

Comment: You must not include the port in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, just `localhost`.